# ASP NET MVC: How to specify the route which starts with a specific URL and ends with specific url?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC controller with few endpoints. One of them should match all following urls:

1. proxy/spell-checker/a/check
2. proxy/spell-checker/a/b/check
3. proxy/spell-checker/a/b/c/check

So, my endpoint should match all routes which start with "proxy/spell-checker" and ends with "check".

**Edit:** the idea is that this endpoint is used for proxy. It should perform a redirect to the relative resource defined between "proxy/spell-checker" and "check". So, a,b,c are not parameters. This is relative path. And it is not consistent!. it could be c/b/a/d/e or d/a/c, etc. I know that this is weird, but this is what the UI library generates and i cannot change it.

The following code throws exception "A catch-all parameter can only appear as the last segment of the route template.":

```
[HttpPost, Route(template: "proxy/spell-checker" + "/{*url}" + "/check")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Check(...)
{
    ...
}
```

How to specify correct route template?

Comment: What is a ? b? and c?   if they are the same in the each route or completely different? Can you post the examples of url please?

Answer (score 1):

nothing can be more simple

```
[Route("~/proxy/spell-checker/{a}/{check}")]
[Route("~/proxy/spell-checker/{a}/{b}/{check}")]
[Route("~/proxy/spell-checker/{a}/{b}/{c}/{check}")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Check(string a, string b, string c, string check)
```

if a,b,c are not parameters, but constants , just remove {}

Comment: If it were that easy, I wouldn't be asking this question. I updated my original question to be more clear